# configure error while setting up emacs from source

Tags: emacs

Here is the detail:

`Checking build system type... configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one`

ubuntu14.04 LTS, emacs 24.5. How to fix this?

Comment: How about trying the recipe of Xah Lee for building Emacs on Ubuntu Linux?  http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/building_emacs_on_linux.html

Answer (score 0):

From the INSTALL file:

> 2) In the unlikely event that 'configure' does not detect your system
>   type correctly, consult './etc/MACHINES' to see what --host, --build
>   options you should pass to 'configure'.  That file also offers hints
>   for getting around some possible installation problems.